# How did we determine degree of given homogeneous function?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Firstly, to find the degree, the function must be polynomial in that variable. And $F(x,y) =cos(y/x)$ is not polynomial in x,y though it can be proved homogeneous.

proof of homogeneous: $F(λx,λy)=cos(λy/λx)=(λ^0)(cos(y/x))=(λ^0)F(x,y)$ degree given in book is 0.

Comment: `(λ^0)F(x,y) degree given in book is 0` That's the same $\color{red}{0}$ as the one in $\lambda^{\color{red}{0}}$ by the definition of [homogeneous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function).

Comment: that means we need not check whether the function is polynomial in that variable or not.

Comment: Right. To be sure, review (and quote if necessary) the definition of homogeneity that you are using.